# How do I generate 5000 synthetic data sets in R with 1000 observations in each that are gaussian;

Tags: r, set, synthetic

for each I need to  For each data set, set σ 2 = 10 and µj = j, where j = 1, . . . , 5, 000 is the index of a data set.

Comment: This seems like homework. What have you done so far to try solving this yourself?

Comment: Just trying to learn R :) thanks for you kind feedback tho

Comment: That's fine, but revisit the guidance for posting a [mcve]. It's expected that your question has some level of an example, code, expected output, research, etc

Answer (score 1):

We can use `lapply` to loop through 1 to 5000 and design a simple function to apply the data to the `rnorm` function.

```
lapply(1:5000, function(x) rnorm(n = 1000, mean = x, sd = sqrt(10)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `purrr::map()`.

```
map(1:5000, ~ rnorm(n = 10000, mean = .x, sd = 10))
```

If you want to iterate over two different arguments to `rnorm`:

```
n_arg <- c(rep(10000, 2500), rep(20000, 2500))
map2(1:5000, n_arg, ~ rnorm(n = .y, mean = .x, sd = 10))
```